# memory allocation in array of structure using double pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Below is the sample code for populating the array of struct `R` using double pointers. I am unable to allocate memory to `r[0]` and also when the function exits, both `r` and `r[0]` becomes `0x0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct R
{
  int x;
  int y;
  char * z;
};

void func(struct R **r)
{
  r = (struct R **) malloc(4 * sizeof(struct R *));
  r[0] = (struct R *) malloc(sizeof(struct R));   // giving r[0] = 0x0
  r[0]->x = 1;
  r[0]->y = 2;
  r[0]->z = (char *) malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(r[0]->z , "HELLO");
}

int main()
{
  struct R *r = NULL;
  func(&r);
  printf("%d", r->x);
  printf("%d", r->y);
  printf("%s", r->z);
  return 0;
}
```

I am unable to find the reason behind it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line

```
r = (struct R **) malloc(4 * sizeof(struct R *));
```

changes where `r` points but only locally in the function. It does not change the value of the pointer in the calling function.

What you need is:

```
void func(struct R **r)
{
   *r = malloc(sizeof(struct R));

   r[0]->x = 1;
   r[0]->y = 2;
   r[0]->z = malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
   strcpy(r[0]->z , "HELLO");
}
```

Another option is to change the return value of `func` to a pointer and make it simpler to use.

```
struct R * func()
{
   struct R *r = malloc(sizeof(*r));

   r->x = 1;
   r->y = 2;
   r->z = malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
   strcpy(r->z , "HELLO");

   return r;
}
```

and use it in `main` as:

```
struct R *r = func();
```

**PS** See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) to understand why you should not cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: An even better recommendation (than the usual "don't cast malloc") would be to use the `sizeof` operator on the actual *variable*, instead of repeating the type again. I.e. `int *x = malloc(sizeof *x)` always works and is a simple rule to remember, while the main problem with casting malloc (implicit `int` function declaration) is no longer an issue as of C11, and not even with earlier compilers with proper warnings enabled.

Answer (score 4):

You want an array of `struct R`, then why are you reserving space for an array of pointers to `struct R`?

Change to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct R
{
  int x;
  int y;
  char * z;
};

void func(struct R **r)
{
  /* Dereference in order to change the value of r */
  *r = malloc(4 * sizeof(struct R)); /* Don't cast malloc */
  r[0]->x = 1;
  r[0]->y = 2;
  r[0]->z = malloc(64); /* char is always 1 byte */
  strcpy(r[0]->z , "HELLO");
}

int main(void) /* Correct prototype */
{
  struct R *r = NULL;

  func(&r);
  printf("%d", r[0].x);
  printf("%d", r[0].y);
  printf("%s", r[0].z);
  /* Don't forget to free */
  free(r[0].z);
  free(r);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
void func(struct R **r)
{
  r = (struct R **) malloc(4 * sizeof(struct R *));
```

No matter what type `r` is, it's still a local variable. If you assign a local variable, the caller part won't be affected. This code is similar to

```
void func(int r)
{
  r = 1;
}
```